# How can I make two identical types two distinguishable types

Tags: c++, c++20, type-safety

How can I make non-primitive types `A` and `B` two distinguishable types in order to add type safety to the interface of function `f`?

```
constexpr std::size_t type_size{ 8U };
using A = std::array<char, type_size>;
using B = std::array<char, type_size>;

constexpr auto f(A const a, B const b)
{
   // Not shown logic here.
}
```

Comment: Just for context, this problem is commonly called a "strong typedef"